# Android: Accessing elements in a Listview's Row and storing them in Strings

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, listadapter

I am working on an application that has a `ListView` of movies declared in the `strings.xml` file as a string array. Each `ListView` row has 3 elements, a.) Movie title b.) Gross c.) Date released. When a row is long clicked, it brings up the option of editting that particular row. if the user clicks on that, he/she is brought to the next screen, where 3 `EditTexts`, corresponding to Title, Gross and Date, where they can edit said entry. The edittext must be populated first with the initial data however.

My problem is that, I can't seem to access the data of the `ListView`, so the "Edit Screen" doesnt get populated with initial data. The code has no errors, but I know Im doing something wrong, i just cant put my finger on it. Here's my code for the 1st screen:

```
public void editEntry(int id) {
    Intent newData = new Intent(Lab8_082588.this, Lab8_082588Add.class);
    TextView movieTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView movieGross = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gross);
    TextView movieDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

    String startTitle = movieTitle.getText().toString();
    String startGross = movieGross.getText().toString();
    String startDate = movieDate.getText().toString();

    newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING, startTitle);
    newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING, startGross);
    newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.DATE_STRING, startDate);
    startActivityForResult(newData, Lab8_082588.EDIT_MOVIE);
}
```

My Adapter class:

```
    private class SampleCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    public SampleCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> movies) {
        internalList = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return internalList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return internalList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        // extract the views to be populated
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView gross = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gross);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

        // extract the object that will fill these
        Lab8_082588FetchDetails movie = internalList.get(position);

        title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        date.setText(movie.getDate());
        gross.setText(movie.getGross());

        // return the view
        return view;
    }
}
```

My EditMovies Activity:

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addedit);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent prepopulate = getIntent();
    EditText movieTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    EditText movieGross = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGross);
    EditText movieDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);

    String startTitle =  prepopulate.getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING);
    String startGross = prepopulate.getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING);
    String startDate = prepopulate.getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.DATE_STRING);

    movieTitle.setText(startTitle);
    movieGross.setText(startGross);
    movieDate.setText(startDate);
}
```

My FetchDetails class

```
    public class Lab8_082588FetchDetails implements Comparable<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>     {

private String title;
private String gross;
private String date;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getGross() {
    return gross;
}

public void setGross(String gross) {
    this.gross = gross;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Lab8_082588FetchDetails another) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.compareTo(another.title);
}

}
```

My Context Item Selected:

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit Entry") {
        editEntry(item.getItemId());
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete Entry") {
        deleteEntry(item.getItemId());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How do I remedy this?

Comment: what is the source of your ListView data population ?

Comment: Can you post your `Movies` class?

Comment: It is declared in a strings.xml as a string array. It has 3 strings-arrays, each corresponding to title, gross and date. it's fairly long so i can;t copy paste it all.

Comment: @BlaineOmega I believe it's already posted there as  public SampleCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> movies) {
        internalList = movies;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[ListView].setOnItemClickListiner(listOnItemClickListener );` method and use the position index to get the respective movie's data:

```
OnItemClickListener listOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {

                    Lab8_082588FetchDetails movie = internalList.get(position);

                    //instead of passing int value pass movie object.
                    editEntry(movie);

                     //newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING, movie.getTitle());
                     //newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING, movie.getGross());
                     //newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.DATE_STRING, movie.getDate());

                     //startActivityForResult(newData, Lab8_082588.EDIT_MOVIE);

    }
};
```

If this does not work for you, you can use `View.setTag()` to tag data to the view in `getView()` and `View.getView()` to get that data.

Comment: Hm. Is there anyway to put this inside the editEntry functioned I declared? Also, internalList is a local variable SampleCustomAdapter class

Comment: made some changes in answer, you have to change editEntry() signature though.

Comment: Ok I managed to create my editEntry class, my problem now is that, is there a way to change the parameter type of editEntry? I updated the post. I guess you have to change the  editEntry(item.getItemId()); part